# Receive SMS like a modem

Tags: sms, serial-port, sms-gateway

I have an application which can only send SMS to a serial AT modem, but I want to send this SMS via an web service.

My idea is to connect a virtual software modem to the (virtual) serial port of the application and receive the SMS in software, then I would pass this SMS to the web API.

My problem is, that i nether find a software which can recieve SMS like a modem nor find a library which offers ability to act like a modem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing application expects to connect to a serial port. That means you need some kind of virtual serial port. Google will give you perfectly usable hits for that term. Any of those libs should give you a character stream.

Parsing this stream should be fairly straightforward. You can toss out all modem initialization, and just focus on the SMS command. In theory, there's a "write" and a "send" command, but you can safely assume that a PC application will send any SMS that it writes. It's not like PC's make typo's. Hence, you just need to parse the `AT+CMGW` command; all other commands can get a standard OK response.

Grab the phone number and message from the `AT+CMGW` command, and pass it to the webservice. Done!

Comment: Thank's for your response! The application will run in a virtual machine, therefore I can redirect the serial port to a pipe. I was afraid, I've to implement this myself, as I didn't find any implementation. Thank's for the short instruction, that showed me it's not as complicated as I thought at first.